# AWS Dynamodb test using swift 3 error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, overriding

I really don't ask questions on stackoverflow except when i really cannot find solution all over the internet.
I have an overriding method problem here. This is the AWS generated code for the DynamoDB. Im using swift 3.0
I tried to remove the override but no use i get this error:

> /Users/*****_*****/Desktop/APPS/Beer On The Go/AmazonAws/Models/NoSQL/Bars.swift:57:16: Method 'JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey()' with Objective-C selector 'JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey' conflicts with method 'jsonKeyPathsByPropertyKey()' from superclass 'AWSDynamoDBObjectModel' with the same Objective-C selector

Any hints to solve this issue?

```
    override class func JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [NSObject : AnyObject] {
    return [
           "_userId" as NSObject : "userId" as AnyObject,
           "_barId" as NSObject : "barId" as AnyObject,
           "_category" as NSObject : "Category" as AnyObject,
           "_description" as NSObject : "Description" as AnyObject,
           "_name" as NSObject : "Name" as AnyObject,
    ]
}
```

[image: Error msg]

Comment: Have you double checked the return type of the superclass method?

Comment: Keg - you should really tick the great answer below!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the updated types for Swift 3 implementation & the new method name (notice lowercase "json"):

```
public override static func jsonKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [AnyHashable : Any]
    return [
           "_userId" as AnyHashable : "userId" as Any,
           "_barId" as AnyHashable : "barId" as Any,
           "_category" as AnyHashable : "Category" as Any,
           "_description" as AnyHashable : "Description" as Any,
           "_name" as AnyHashable : "Name" as Any
    ]
}
```

Comment: Here is a problem I have in using the same sample code in this era; it may help anyone goggling here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615830/weird-swift-3-issue-with-latest-amazon-aws-mobile-sample-code