# Weird Swift 3 issue with latest Amazon AWS Mobile sample code

Tags: swift3, aws-sdk

Following along the current sample code for aws.amazon.com/mobile/ there are a number of code items they have not updated really well to Swift 3 (which is pretty bizarre considering their resources).

When you come to AWSMobileClient.swift there's a line of code like this:

```
 if (!isInitialized) {
 AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().resumeSession(completionHandler:
   {(result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    print("Result: \(result) \n Error:\(error)")
    } as! (Any?, Error?) -> Void)
 isInitialized = true
 }
```

which just crashes on any run.

Fortunately I was able to fix it by changing the arguments like so

```
  AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().resumeSession(completionHandler:
        {(result: Any?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            print("Result: \(result) \n Error:\(error)")
        } as! (Any?, Error?) -> Void)
```

The problem is this, I get the warning

[image]

indeed it seems pointless trying to cast it to the same type.

**BUT if you simply delete the cast**

```
AWSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().resumeSession(completionHandler:
       {(result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        print("Result: \(result) \n Error:\(error)")
        }
     isInitialized = true
```

that just doesn't work at all, you get all sorts of weird syntax errors

[image]

1) Why is there a cast there anyway?

2) How can I get rid of the cast, or write it properly so there's no identical cast and hence no warning?

3) I guess a solution is just to remove the force (so, `as` rather than `as!`) but I really don't understand why you have to cast the block there.

---

*Note* - at that same line of code, Amazon include a comment *"If you get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS here in iOS Simulator, then do Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings..., This will clear bad auth tokens stored by other apps with the same bundle ID."*  The issue I'm asking about here is totally unrelated to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the last example which is presumably the proper syntax the closing parenthesis is missing.

You replaced

```
} as (Any?, Error?) -> Void)
```

with

`}` rather than expected `})`

I deleted everything which is not mandatory to make it clearer:

```
WSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().resumeSession(completionHandler: { (result, error) in
    print("Result: \(result) \n Error:\(error)")
})
isInitialized = true
```

or still shorter with trailing closure syntax:

```
WSIdentityManager.defaultIdentityManager().resumeSession() { (result, error) in
    print("Result: \(result) \n Error:\(error)")
}
isInitialized = true
```

The type annotations (in completion blocks) are not needed. They could do more harm than good.

PS: Isn't `isInitialized` supposed to be **in** the completion block?

Comment: (PS, regarding the `isInitialized` I too figure it should be in that completion block; not sure what they're up to there: seems to work.)

Comment: I don't like that questioners edit my answers, so I edited it `my way` ;-)